# Sitecore 8.1 : sitecore_fxm_web_index - Root item could not be found

Tags: lucene, sitecore

We are using Sitecore 8.1 powered by Lucene index and xDB disabled.

We noticed that the CMS CA is quiet slow. While looking at logs noticed a number of error logged below:

```
ManagedPoolThread #4 2015:12:18 10:17:05 ERROR [Index=sitecore_fxm_web_index, Crawler=SitecoreItemCrawler, Database=web] Root item could not be found: /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/fxm/.


ManagedPoolThread #15 2015:12:18 10:17:08 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.MethodInstance.Invoke()
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: [Index=sitecore_fxm_web_index, Crawler=SitecoreItemCrawler, Database=web] Root item could not be found: /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/fxm/.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.get_RootItem()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsAncestorOf(Item item)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId, Boolean checkLocation)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.Update(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.PerformUpdate(IEnumerable`1 indexableInfo, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.Update(IEnumerable`1 indexableInfo)
```

Could someone please suggest why sitecore is looking for Web forms for marketing index which we don't need it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore looks for `sitecore_fxm_web_index` index. It's not a WFFM index - it's Federated Experience Manager Index. This is an integral part of Sitecore 8.1.

Here you can read more about [Federated Experience Manager](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/federated%20experience%20manager).

Looks like you're missing root item of this index, which is `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/fxm/`. I guess you're migration process from Sitecore 7 (which you mentioned in other question) to Sitecore 8.1 was not 100% successful.

Comment: Thank you again. Should this node /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/fxm/ be created as part of Sitecore 8.1 installation? Yep we migrated just our content e.g. news, articles, our IA, template, images only.

Comment: `/sitecore/system/marketing cotrol panel/fxm` item (its display name is `Federated Experience Manager`) is a part of Sitecore 8.1. Do you have this item in `master` database? Was it published to `web` database?

Comment: @MarekMusielak what configuration indicates the DB that is checked for this? We get the error that it's missing, but I suspect it's looking at a legacy/bad DB...